# Gradient theorem in line integrals

Tags: multivariable-calculus, vector-fields

For the line integral
$$\int_{C} \left( \frac{dx}{x} + z^2 dy + 2yz dz \right)$$ where $C$ is the path of the line segment from $(1,0,0)$ to $(1,2,1)$ followed by the line segment from $(1,2,1)$ to $(2,1,4)$.
Can I employ the gradient theorem here? Is it safe to say that the vector field $\mathbf{f}$ is conservative? I found that the curl of the vector field is zero, BUT there's a singularity at $x=0$. However, the path never passes through that $x=0$, so is this okay?

Answer (score 0):

Yes - the vector field is conservative.

The integrand is  $\vec {\nabla} f \cdot d \vec r$
where $f$ is the scalar field given by 
$$f(x,y,z)=\ln x + yz^2$$

The value of the integral depends only on the endpoints of your path.

Comment: Thanks. I think my query is mostly based on the other question - in the other comment on this thread

Answer (score 0):

Well you can definitely write

$$ \int_{C} \left( \frac{dx}{x} + z^2 dy + 2yz dz \right) = \int_{C} \nabla (\ln(x) + yz^2)\cdot(dx,dy,dz).  $$

Then the gradient theorem implies that line integrals through gradient fields are path independent. See [Gradient theorem wiki](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gradient_theorem) for more on this.

To answer your question in the comment below. Every conservative field can be written as the gradient of a scalar field. This is what I have done above.

So what we have done is written a conservative vector field $\mathbf{V}(r)$ as the gradient of some scalar field $\nabla S(r)$ i.e.

$$ \mathbf{V}(r) = \nabla S(r). $$
Now, we are free to take the curl of the above i.e.

$$ \nabla \times \mathbf{V}(r) = \nabla \times \nabla S(r) = 0. $$

In vector calculus the curl of a gradient is zero. Hence, the curl of a conservative vector field  $\mathbf{V}(r)$ is always zero!

Comment: How would we determine that it is conservative via looking at its curl and region? I recall that if the curl is zero AND the region (domain?) is simply connected, it is conservative. Why is this region simply connected?

Comment: @PaulWoch I've edited my answer to address why the curl of a conservative vector field is always zero.